# Specify JWT authentication scheme per request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

I have a web application that implements Azure B2C-based authentication for an unlimited number of B2C tenants. The application sets a context at runtime based on the host subdomain, which in turn selects the appropriate tenant.

This works easily enough on the client side since the application only runs on the user's browser under a single context at any given time. However, since there is only one instance of the API layer, this must be able to simultaneously support requests coming from a number of different users using bearer tokens issued by a number of different tenants.

I use the following code to add authentication schemes at startup for each of the tenants. The scheme name is equal to the url of the source context:

```
        foreach (Context context in Contexts)
        {

            services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddJwtBearer(context.url,
                jwtOptions =>
                {
                    jwtOptions.Authority = context.tenant;
                    jwtOptions.Audience = context.client;
                }
            );

        }
```

My question is, how do I tell the authentication middleware which scheme to use in order to validate the user's bearer token? Is there a way this somehow happens automatically, or do I instead need to create a custom AuthorizeAttribute?

Thanks!

UPDATE: I was able to get this to work by creating and registering a custom policy provider as indicated below:

```
internal class MyCustomPolicyProvider : IAuthorizationPolicyProvider
{

    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public MyCustomPolicyProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetDefaultPolicyAsync()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString());
        return Task.FromResult(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(uri.Host).RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
    }


    public Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetPolicyAsync(string policyName)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString());
        return Task.FromResult(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(uri.Host).RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
    }

}
```

The controllers are then protected like this:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "MyCustom")]
```

This feels a little clunky but it does work. One thing I don't quite understand is why both GetPolicyAsync() and GetDefaultPolicyAsync() which are required by IAuthorizationPolicyProvider are run on each authorization. It seems we should only need GetPolicyAsync() so the other call is redundant.

Comment: You could call AuthenticateAsync on the HttpContext in a middleware after figuring out the caller tenant from URL/headers. It allows you to specify the scheme name.

Comment: Hi @christok. What if you add the authorization policy at startup as per [Use multiple authentication schemes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-multiple-authentication-schemes)? Is the authorization policy built for each request?

Answer (score 0):

As @juunas suggest , you can choose the scheme you want to authenticate based on httpcontext items dynamically :

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var host = context.Request.Host.ToString();
    if (true)
    {
        var result = await context.AuthenticateAsync("YourScheme");
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;  
            return;
        }

    }
    ....

    await next();
});
```

You can also create custom Authentication handler to read request ,validate token use [JwtSecurityTokenHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytokenhandler?view=azure-dotnet) and at last sign in user using [cookie authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1) .

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I did try this approach but it didn't quite accomplish what I'd hoped. However, I updated the question and would appreciate any thoughts you might have on that!